# Tensorflow not able to import in vs code?

Tags: tensorflow, visual-studio-code

[I made environment , install tensorflow with pip, but why its not able to import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHJk7.png)

Comment: Please include your image inline

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code / Pylance / Pylint Cannot resolve import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65271399/vs-code-pylance-pylint-cannot-resolve-import)